# How do I read binary serialized Avro (Confluent Platform) from Kafka using Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

These are Avros serialized with the Confluent platform.

I would like to find a working example like this:

https://github.com/seanpquig/confluent-platform-spark-streaming/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/StreamingJob.scala

but for Spark Structured Streaming.

```
 kafka
   .select("value")
   .map { row => 

     // this gives me test == testRehydrated    
     val test = Foo("bar") 
     val testBytes = AvroWriter[Foo].toBytes(test)
     val testRehydrated = AvroReader[Foo].fromBytes(testBytes)


     // this yields mangled Foo data
     val bytes = row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value") 
     val rehydrated = AvroReader[Foo].fromBytes(bytes)
```

Comment: Did you find a working solution?

Comment: @aasthetic see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out you have to use the Confluent platform decoder if you want to read their stuff.

```
def decoder: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder = {
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, getSchemaRegistryUrl())
  props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true")
  val vProps = new kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties(props)
  new io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder(vProps)
}
```

Comment: thanks @zzztimbo, I also registered schema for my keys, they have to be of Long type. I am unable to deserialise them in Spark Streaming. Any idea?

Comment: It would be helpful to get a complete example of how to setup structured streaming, with a kafka topic + schema registry. It's not clear to me what to do with this decoder.

Answer (score 3):

We have been working on this library which may help: [ABRiS (Avro Bridge for Spark)](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS)

It provides APIs for integrating Spark to Avro in both, read and write operations (streaming and batch). It also supports Confluent Kafka and integrates with Schema Registry.

DISCLAIMER: I work for ABSA and I am the main developer behind this library.

Comment: after adding ABRiS dependencies to the POM file the method `fromAvro` is not there when I tried ABRiS with spark java api . Any help ?

Comment: @Vignesh, the library is written in Scala but should be possible to be imported into a Java class. How are you trying to import it?

Comment: after adding all the necessary dependencies in pom i.e(confluent and abris) I tried to import ABRiS libs as said in https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS Read me, but at the line `Dataset<Row> ds = sparksession.readstream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.server","localhost:9092").option("subscribe","topicname"). method` fromavro is not there in the eclipse intellisense and there is no issue in build

Comment: `fromConfluentAvro` is not there even after all the imports, but in scala it works fine.

Comment: `fromConfluentAvro` method is not popping up in eclipse intelisense when we use java, but in scala it works fine. could you please shed some light on ABRiS using java